# How to add an anchor to an address when opening a modal window?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

The site uses windows on Uikit. 
How can I add an anchor to an address when a modal window is called?

Comment: Please insert your [code](/help/mcve) to your question! Without code it's hard to help you.

Comment: So, you want to put a link inside a modal window? Or, you want to have a link open a modal window?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma, i need to put a link when windows open.

Comment: @Григорий Sorry, I'm still not understanding - do you (1) want to put a link inside a modal, (2) want to have a link on your page that opens a modal, or (3) want to have your page's URL change when the modal is opened so that people can link to that modal (Chrome Settings / `window.history` style)

Comment: @Toastrackenigma, 3) item.

Comment: @Григорий Hey, I've written a solution for you! I posted it before I finished by mistake, but all done now :)  Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Introduction

So, from what I understand (I clarified this with OP in the question comments), we want to change the URL whenever the user opens a modal / closes a modal, to provide a link to that modal. Google Chrome does a similar thing in its Settings page, and I can see a few other use cases for this as well.

We could use the `window.history` API, as this is the kind of thing it is designed for. However, this probably gives us extra work - if someone enters one of those URLs you need server rules for dealing with it (e.g. .htaccess stuff), and I'd rather keep this one working for as many people as possible.

Therefore, I'm going to use the `#` portion of the URL. The idea is that if the user opens a modal, the end of the URL might change to `#modalOne` (for example), and change back to `#` when the user closes it. If the user manually enters a `#`, or clicks one in a link, the respecting modal will show up (if such a modal exists).

This will be done in two parts: making the modals add / remove the `#` URLs, and showing modals based off of the URL.

## Code

I want this to be as simple and extensible as possible for you - it should be easy to scale from using it for 1 modal to 100 without writing any extra code.

The method that seems to work best is using a data attribute on the modal to specify its `#` URL title. A data attribute is just a custom HTML attribute that you can put onto any element. In our case, it will go on the same element with the UIKit `uk-modal` attribute on it. I've decided to call it `data-modal`, but you can call it anything as long as you're consistent everywhere else we reference it and start the name with `data-`.

Here's how a modal definition might look:

```
<div id="modal" uk-modal data-modal="test">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Modal</h2>
        Some modal window<br>
        <button class="uk-modal-close" type="button">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This modal has a `data-modal` attribute of `test` - meaning that it will change the URL to end in `#test` when it is open.

Now, we need to actually implement this. You need to add the following JS code somewhere on your page:

```
let isChangingModal = false;

window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    for (let modal of document.querySelectorAll("[data-modal]")) {
        modal.addEventListener("beforeshow", ()=>{
            isChangingModal = true;
            window.location.hash = "#" + modal.getAttribute("data-modal");
        });
        modal.addEventListener("beforehide", ()=>{
            isChangingModal = true;
            window.location.hash = "#";
        });
    }

    showModalFromURL();
});     

function showModalFromURL() {
    if (isChangingModal) {
        isChangingModal = false;
        return;
    }
    let modal = document.querySelector(`[data-modal="${window.location.hash.slice(1)}"]`);
    if (modal) {
        UIkit.modal(modal).show();
    }
}

window.onhashchange = showModalFromURL;
```

I will explain how this works below.

## How it Works

When the page loads, we need to add event handlers to all of the modals with `data-modal` attributes - we need to handle the `onbeforeshow` and `onbeforehide` events. This allows us to call code when these modals are shown or hidden. Note that this means you can leave a modal out of this scheme by simply not adding a `data-modal` attribute to it.

We do this by looping over all of the modals with the attribute on page load.

> Note: This assumes you don't add modals via JS after the page is loaded. If you do, just change this to a function, and call it both on page load AND whenever you add a new modal.

`document.querySelectorAll("[data-modal]")` gives you all DOM nodes for elements which have that attribute - look at the relevant documentation (CSS attribute selectors & MDN for querySelector) for more info. We then loop through them one-by-one, and add both events to them.

In each event handler, we want to change the `#` part of the URL - so we do. When you open the modal, we change it to `"#" + modal.getAttribute("data-modal")` - this means a `#` before whatever value you set that attribute to. For closing, we just set it to a hash.

This is all we need for part one. For part two, I wrote a function that checks what is in the hash, attempts to find a modal with a `data-modal` attribute with the same value, and if it does, shows it. This needs to happen both on page load (they clicked an external link) and whenever the hash part of the URL changes (they clicked a link on the page, edited the URL, you change it via code elsewhere, etc).

Of course, there was just one problem - the modals themselves change the hash - we don't want opening a modal to cause itself to be opened which would then cause itself to be opened which would then.........

That is why we have the `isChangingModal` boolean. If that is true, it means we are changing a modal, and the subsequent hash change is not to be used as an event.

Otherwise, we use a querySelector to find the modal, and then UIKit to open it.

*Let me know if there's anything wrong / you have any issue with this implementation.*

## Further Reading

- [`document.querySelector` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [CSS Attribute Selectors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [UIKit Modal JS Documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#javascript)

## Using with UIKit 2.25

UIKit only has `hide` and `show` events (rather than `beforehide` and `beforeshow) - the difference being they fire *after* the animations, not before them. This shouldn't really be a big problem to port to.

The bigger issue is that they don't work natively, only with jQuery. If you're fine with that, here's a little part of my code from before modified to work with these different events - replace the similar part in that script with this and you should be good to go:

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{

    for (let modal of document.querySelectorAll("[data-popup]")) {
        $(modal).on({
            "show.uk.modal" : ()=>{
                isChangingModal = true;
                window.location.hash = "#" + modal.getAttribute("data-popup");
            },

            "hide.uk.modal" : ()=>{
                isChangingModal = true;
                window.location.hash = "#";
            }
        });
    }

    showModalFromURL();
});
```

Comment: Incredibly. 
I'm trying to use the code. But so far it is not functioning. I think because my modal window is called like this: <button class= "button uk-buttonlarge ukbutton-danger" data-uk-modal= " {target:'#my-id2081'} " >More< / button>

This reason can prevent your code from running?

Comment: I used a button like that in my test, and everything worked fine. Are there any errors in the console? Here's my stripped down test HTML file; check if that works for you: https://pastebin.com/sfK4Z33B

Comment: Console clean. Popup work, but url dont change.
In code pen this code supposed to work? 
https://codepen.io/Grione/pen/vbvBoq

Comment: Ah, CodePen doesn't show you the URL. Try it as just a standalone web page (e.g. `.html` file)

Comment: I think problem in Uikit version. Joomla Them use Uikit 2.25.0. 
But i dont understand why this problem.

Comment: I did not use the name data-model because there was an error in the console. I took a data-popup. No error, but the url does not change.
this is my example http://test.endlesstest.ru

Comment: Did you get it going in the end? Because it works for me when I visit the site. Otherwise, maybe there's a browser / OS related bug? What system are you running?

Comment: No. ( 
I've been experimenting with your code. look now. 
Maybe version 2.25 doesn't support beforeshow, beforehide events?

Comment: None of these events ( "beforeshow" , "beforehide")  in version 2.25...

Comment: Hey, did't realise you were using 2.25. I've made an edit at the bottom of my post which uses events that *are* supported in that version, so hopefully that fixes any problems for you.

Comment: It's working! You've been incredibly helpful. Thanks a lot. It's nice to know that there are people who are so sincere to help.

Comment: Glad I could help :)